# Access Fields of Firebase Firestore Document In Swift and ios 14?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First off, I'm very new to firebase, so this may be an easy question to answer. I am using firestore on firebase to save usernames and full names under a document with the user's email as its name and within a collection titled `users`. With ios 14, there is no `AppDelegate` page so I've been placing stuff that deals with firebase under this:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
                        launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```

I see this sample code to get a document:

```
let docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF")

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

but after this I do not know how to access the usernames and fullnames. Or even how to properly store this document? What do I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get values of fields from the retrieved document you can this:

```
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        
        let data = document.data()
        let username = data!["username"]! as? String ?? ""
        let fieldName = data!["fieldName"]! as? String ?? ""
        print(username)
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```